# Multi-row INSERT rejected at SqlServer2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's wrong with my query? :(

```
USE tempdb;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.OrderTotals', 'V') IS NOT NULL
DROP VIEW dbo.OrderTotals;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.OrderDetails', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.OrderDetails;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderDetails
(
oid INT NOT NULL,
pid INT NOT NULL,
qty INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(oid, pid)
);
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails(oid, pid, qty) VALUES
(10248, 1, 10),
(10248, 2, 20),
(10248, 3, 30),
(10249, 1, 5),
(10249, 2, 10),
(10249, 3, 15),
(10250, 1, 20),
(10250, 2, 20),
(10250, 3, 20);
GO
```

If i execute that query, I got this error

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Which line is highlighted when you double click on that error?

Comment: Works fine on SQL Fiddle without the `DROP TABLE` bits at the top...(minus the `GO`s too). Have you tried running it without the drop table statements?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? I think the "multi-row" insert was only introduced in 2008.

Comment: I think I just broke SQL Fiddle... :( - I tried this with SQL2008 and SQL2012 - didn't try 2005 - will try on my local 2005 server

Comment: This runs fine on my SQL 2008 installation when I copy the query verbatim.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Yes you're right. Before that needed to do `SELECT 10248, 1, 10 UNION ALL SELECT 10248, 2, 20 ...`

Comment: Confirmed - same error on SQL2005

Comment: On a 2000 box, you can't specify an object type to `OBJECT_ID()`. But until the OP responds and tells us which version is involved, we're all just guessing.

Comment: This question does **not** belong on [dba.se]. It hardly fits into the Advanced Querying category mentioned in [the FAQ](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is at line 15 at the ','
Try the following (not tested):

```
USE tempdb;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.OrderTotals', 'V') IS NOT NULL
DROP VIEW dbo.OrderTotals;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.OrderDetails', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.OrderDetails;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderDetails
(
oid INT NOT NULL,
pid INT NOT NULL,
qty INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(oid, pid)
);
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails(oid, pid, qty) VALUES (10248, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails(oid, pid, qty) VALUES (10248, 2, 20);
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails(oid, pid, qty) VALUES (10248, 3, 30);
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails(oid, pid, qty) VALUES (10249, 1, 5);
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails(oid, pid, qty) VALUES (10249, 2, 10);
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails(oid, pid, qty) VALUES (10249, 3, 15);
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails(oid, pid, qty) VALUES (10250, 1, 20);
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails(oid, pid, qty) VALUES (10250, 2, 20);
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails(oid, pid, qty) VALUES (10250, 3, 20);
GO
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. it turns out my sql server is 2005 x_x

Answer (score 1):

You may encounter that error when you try [Multi Row Insert](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/02/sql-server-2008-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-row-constructor/) in SQL Server below SQL Server 2008.

Check out below code it will work even if it is SQL Server 2005:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.OrderDetails', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.OrderDetails;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderDetails
(
oid INT NOT NULL,
pid INT NOT NULL,
qty INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(oid, pid)
);
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails(oid, pid, qty) 
select 10248, 1, 10 union all
select 10248, 2, 20 union all
select 10248, 3, 30 union all
select 10249, 1, 5 union all
select 10249, 2, 10 union all
select 10249, 3, 15 union all
select 10250, 1, 20 union all
select 10250, 2, 20 union all
select 10250, 3, 20
```